# Undefined variable when inserting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm getting an undefined variable when trying to execute my code, the entry gets made in mysql but there is no data being inserted, obviously because of the undefined variable.

It was working...

Here's the message:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: title in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rfx/wp-content/plugins/rfx-manager/inc/rfi_page.php on line 154
```

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $wpdb->query("insert into ".$wpdb->prefix."forms set user_id=".$user_id.",
        title='".$title."');

    $title=$result->title;
    ?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">

<label for="title"><b>Enter title here:</b></label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="large-text" value="<?php echo (isset($title) ? $title : '') ?>" placeholder="Enter title">

    <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Submit RFI for approval' ); ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you should insert the value of `title` in your query _before_ assigning it a value on the next row?

Comment: So... where will you obviously *define* $title?

Comment: It's defined by name="title", how can I pass that through to $title?

Comment: The code shown here is not declaring any `$title`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, basically what the problem was is that one of the variables wasn't of course declared.

The snippet I gave was this:

$title=$result->title;

There were more variables like this stacked, one of them was giving a conflict, I basically went through them one by one adding each one and testing it, that surfaced the issue.

Hope this helps anyone.